# Exception based on condition on Apps Script in Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script I can exclude to insert the same value column in Google Sheet for maximum 100 times.

But I am trying to exclude (with if statement) some values from this script, in particular the date "25/12/2022" and the date "12/01/2012".

How could I proceed?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() === 'New Rise 2022' && r.getColumn() === 27) {
    var newValue = r.getDisplayValue();
    if (newValue == "") return;
    var count = s.getRange('AA1:AA').getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a === newValue).length;
    if (count > 99) {
      r.setValue(e.oldValue);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Questa data è stata già inserita 100 volte');
    }
  }
}
```

Update:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() === 'New Rise 2022' && r.getColumn() === 27) {
    var newValue = r.getDisplayValue();
    if (newValue == "") return;
    var count = s.getRange('AA1:AA').getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a === newValue).length;
    if (count > 99 || e.range.getDisplayValue() == "25/12/2012" || e.range.getDisplayValue() == "12/01/2012") {
      r.setValue(e.oldValue);
    r.setNumberFormat('dd/mm/YYYY'); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Questa data è stata già inserita 100 volte');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can get the newly entered display value and compare it against the "forbidden" values

Therefore, retrieve the latest modified cell with `e.range`:

```js
    ...
    if (count > 99 || e.range.getDisplayValue() == "25/12/2022" || e.range.getDisplayValue() == "12/01/2012") {
      ...
    }
   ...
```

**Note:**

I understood that what you are interested in is the displayed value (date in this case), but depending on your date formatting the display value will be different from the value you typed in.

If it is the typed in value you are after, you can retrieve it with `e.value`:

```js
    ...
    console.log("e.value: " + e.value)
    console.log("e.range.getDisplayValue(): " + e.range.getDisplayValue())
    if (count > 99 || e.value == "25/12/2022" || e.value == "12/01/2012") {
      ...
    }
   ...
```

**References:**

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getdisplayvalue)

**UPDATE:**

If you have problems with number formatting you can use the method [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat).

Modify your code block in the `if` statement to

```js
r.setValue(e.oldValue);
r.setNumberFormat('dd/mm/YYYY');
```

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka thanks for your reply. I have tried with both solutions, but not works

Comment: After I have insert your code, if I write the date 12/01/2012, in the cell return the value 44573.0

Comment: Sounds like there is a formatting problem in your sheet - the date is interpreted as a number. Try to change the formatting  in your date column through the Sheets UI menu by selecting the column (or range of interest) and then going on "Format"->"Number"->"Custom Date and Time". You probably want to select the formatting dd/mm/YYYY .

Comment: Hello. The format is correct dd/mm/YYYY (Custom Date and Time), but return 44573.0...

Comment: Hmmm...  44573.0 is the result of 12/01/2012 formatted as a number... So, when did this number show up? After a user typed in a value or after the script reset the value? Can you share a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: After the script reset the value…

Comment: And you are still using `e.oldValue` for this? Can you log it? I still think the problem is the formatting of your sheet. If for whatever reason you cannot modify it from the UI - try with Apps Script - see my updated answer.

Comment: I have update the code with your addition, but not works...

Comment: You were using the code block with `e.oldValue` already before, so if it wre working for you correctly before, but now it gives you the wrong formatting - there must have been some format change in the sheet that is not related to the new conditonal statement I provided in my answer. If you can porvide a sample spreadsheet with this problem, I can have a look at the formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### How about this?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const x = ["25/12/2022","12/01/2012"];
  const idx = x.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName() === 'New Rise 2022' && e.range.columnStart == 27 && e.value && !~idx) {
    var count = sh.getRange('AA1:AA' + sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat().filter(e => e == e.value).length;
    if (count > 99) {
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
    }
  }
}
```